# Django on production server(ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, django

I'm trying to ship web application to the production server. My setup is **django-gunicorn-nginx** by following this tutorial. I've not installed supervisor yet for checking purpose. There is no problem in the configuration setup. But while I'm running `gunicorn_django --bind=127.0.0.1:8001` It shows

```
cover.backgroundmodel: "background": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
cover.backgroundmodel: "tmpbg": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
2012-05-22 14:24:02 [15359] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15359)
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15360] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15360
2012-05-22 14:24:02 [15360] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15360)
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15349] [INFO] Handling signal: int
2012-05-23 00:54:02 [15349] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

But I've successfully installed everything including PIL and other image libraries. The interesting thing is I'm getting my project running perfectly on my computer. But I can't identify the cause of the problem in the production server.

Could anyone help me?

Again I tried installing `pip install PIL` It shows [like this](https://gist.github.com/2771119).  Why is it so? why I can not able to install PIL now which I successfully installed before while installing django.

Answer (score 1):

The error on the gist seems to be the result of gcc looking for python.h, not finding it, and failing. Install the python-dev package:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

and try installing PIL again:

```
pip install pil
```